# Wrong element closes list on click

Tags: jquery, list, click, slidetoggle

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/xFxD3/1/

But when clicking the "li" elements the list closes. Its only supposed to close when you click on one of the "span" elements (Click here 1, Click here 2).

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$('.test').click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find('.toggle').slideToggle("fast");
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

The click binding was on the parent `<li>` tag instead of the `<span>` tags.

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xFxD3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.test').click(function() { 
    $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xFxD3/1/ ​